# std::string.size() unknown behavior

Tags: c++

I expected  `Output 1` to be equal to `Output 2`, because of simple addition and subtraction, the bracket's should make no difference
Here's the Output:

> ```
> Output 1: 3
> Output 2: 4294967295
> Output 1: 6
> Output 2: 2
> ```

I think it's something about the string.size(), but I can't explain to myself how this may happen. Maybe someone can help me understand this.

```
int lastPos = 0;
std::string inputString = "0b1*10*0";
while (lastPos != -1){
    lastPos = inputString.find('*',lastPos+1);

    if(lastPos != -1){
        // -2 for 0b/ removal
        // 8 Bit max Size
        std::cout << "Output 1: " << lastPos-2 + 8 - (inputString.size()-2) << std::endl;
        std::cout << "Output 2: " << lastPos-2 + 8 - inputString.size()-2 << std::endl;
    }          
}
```

Comment: `... (inputString.size()-2)` vs `... inputString.size()-2` - what happens if `inputString.size()` is less than `2`? The type is unsigned, so it will underlow and produce a huge value in the first case.

Comment: 4 294 967 295 = 0xFFFF FFFF (-1 cast from size_t)

Comment: `A - (B - C) == A - B + C`. Note the plus.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`lastPos-2 + 8 - (inputString.size()-2)` **!=** `lastPos-2 + 8 - inputString.size()-2`

`lastPos-2 + 8 - (inputString.size()-2)` **==** `lastPos-2 + 8 - inputString.size()+2`

Because `-(-2) == +2`